# Can someone explain dialogue expressions? Momotarou

Tags: expressions, dialogue

Trying to read and translate Momotarou and I don't quite understand these expressions.

So far I have

> 「うまい もも こっちゃ こい。

> "Delicious peach ... come.

> Reference translation: Sweet peach come here.

こっちゃ apparently means `as for that thing/matter/fact`. So I can kind of understand it just referring to the peach and not having an effect on an English translation. Correct?

---

> にがい もも あっちゃ いけ。」

> Bitter peach ... go."

> Reference translation: Bitter peach go away.

あっちゃ is supposedly an expression

> stone the crows; blow me down; oops; uh oh; expression of annoyed surprise or shock

But the translated dialogue has no reflection of this. Is it as simple as they just missed an exclamation mark? I might be horribly wrong, but it feels like Japanese dialogue has actual words for one's current emotion whereas English doesn't and it is based solely on the descriptive text before or after the dialogue. Is this something that is actually used in real life speech or only when dialogue is written?

Reference story: http://life.ou.edu/stories/momotarou.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say あっちゃ, こっちゃ here in your example are the contracted pronunciations of あっち**へ**, こっち**へ**.

> うまい もも こっちゃ こい。＜＜ うまい桃、こっちへ来い。
> "Delicious peach, come this way."

> にがい もも あっちゃ いけ。＜＜ 苦い桃、あっちへ行け。
> "Bitter peach, go away."

Comment: So I understand correctly -- へ is used in its particle form for direction in your example?

Comment: Yes, へ is a case particle for direction. こっちへ lit. "to/toward here".

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just had to make sure because I've been bitten by many assumptions so far on this journey.

Comment: @TyCobb You should mark this answer as accepted instead. My answer was only a guess.

Comment: @EddieKal As you wish. It was still very helpful in getting me the nouns that the online dictionaries could not determine.

Answer (score 2):

Here 「こっちゃ」is a diminutive for「こっち」or「こちら」, simply meaning "here".

「あっちゃ」:「あっち」、「あちら」, "over there". Now they should make sense in the context.

Comment: Oh! I guess I got bit by wrong definitions. Dictionaries kept giving me expression definitions and hinting at different verbs. I thought "here" was implied because I knew it as ここ and it didn't have a に particle that hinted it was a location.